# SQL select properties that have available dates

Tags: php, mysql

This is actually a two parter, but feel free to answer only part 1 for now.

## The Tables

```
Property
==============
ID  |  ... |


Calendar
=============
property_id |  start_date | end_date | block_reason
```

The `property` table holds all the data about the property.  The `calendar` table holds ranges of dates that are blocked for whatever reason.  Dates between (and including) the `start_date` and `end_date` are considered blocked.  `property` has a one to many relationship with the `calendar` table.

## The Query (part 1)

I want to select a property that has available dates between a given start and end date.  So far I've tried.

```
SELECT * 
FROM property AS p
LEFT JOIN calendar AS c ON c.property_id=p.id
WHERE (c.start_date IS NULL OR c.start_date > "{my start date}") 
  AND (c.end_date IS NULL OR c.end_date < "{my end date}")
```

This works if the property has no results in the calendar table.  But otherwise fails terribly (empty result set).

## The Query (part 2)

Once we get part 1 working.  The user will also be able to give a number of days available, and we need to select properties that have consecutive days available within the given start-end range.  Basically "I want a property with N days available between X and Y dates."

I've been googling this all morning and none of my friends/coworkers seem to have an idea where to start either.  Because the results are paginated, I want to avoid handling this in PHP and having to do the whole select, filter, repeat until no results or full page, logic shindig.

I appreciate the help.  Thanks.

## Edit

Per request, a fiddle with dummy data.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/854eb/7

Comment: How are your dates formatted?

Comment: The columns are TIMESTAMPS

Comment: Can you describe `fails terribly`? Are you getting an error?

Comment: @chris85 No error, just empty result set.

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset and the query that fails; or possibly a sqlfiddle?

Comment: @chris85 I definitely can try, give me a few minutes.

Comment: @chris85 I added the fiddle to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to count up the number of days between the two and then compare that to the number of days.  Assuming there are no overlaps and the end date is inclusive:

```
SELECT c.property_id
FROM calendar c
WHERE c.start_date <= {my end date} AND
      c.end_date >= {my start date}
GROUP BY c.property_id
HAVING SUM(datediff(greatest({my start date}, c.start_date),
                    least({my end date}, c.end_date)
                   ) + 1
          ) < datediff({my end date} , {my start date}) + 1
```

Comment: This gets me closer and gives me an idea.  I may have to handle this with two or more queries instead of just one big one.

Comment: This worked for me.  I edited your original post to reflect the exact query that worked.  I'll accept your answer if nothing better gets posted, but this was great!  Thanks for your help.